# "en-US-Wavenet-H" and "en-US-Wavenet-G" are not smooth [Google Cloud Text to Speech]

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I'm testing Google Cloud Text to Speech. I succeeded in getting the wav audio file, but the sound is not smooth in certain voices, especially "en-US-Wavenet-H" and "en-US-Wavenet-G".

[wav file I created(en-US-Wavenet-H, LINEAR16)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ej36CNlrHfBOmzXiJ3jLSLkbx-Z_647P/view?usp=sharing)

[Google's demo page(please select "en-US-Wavenet-H")](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech#section-2)

I used the same json with the demo page. This is my code.

```
<audio controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay" id="audio">
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var url = 'https://texttospeech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/text:synthesize?key=API_KEY';
        var data = `{
          "audioConfig": {
            "audioEncoding": "LINEAR16",
            "pitch": 0,
            "speakingRate": 1
          },
          "input": {
            "text": "Google Cloud Text-to-Speech enables developers to synthesize natural-sounding speech with 100+ voices, available in multiple languages and variants. It applies DeepMind’s groundbreaking research in WaveNet and Google’s powerful neural networks to deliver the highest fidelity possible. As an easy-to-use API, you can create lifelike interactions with your users, across many applications and devices."
          },
          "voice": {
            "languageCode": "en-US",
            "name": "en-US-Wavenet-H"
          }
        }`;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', url);
        request.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (request.readyState != 4) {
            } else if (request.status != 200) {
            } else {
                var result = request.responseText;
                var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                document.getElementById("audio").setAttribute('src', 'data:audio/x-wav;base64,' + obj.audioContent);
            }
        };
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        request.send(data);
</script>
```

I also tried it with Windows Power Shell & Cloud SDK and the result was the same.
"en-US-Wavenet-I" and "en-US-Wavenet-J" aren't too terrible, but not smooth. Other voices are okay. Why can't I get the same audio as the demo? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/create-audio#text-to-speech-ssml-python) tutorial to create the audio file? Also, I did not see much of a difference in your audio file to the Demo. However, if you believe there is a quality issue you can file an issue at [Google's Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

Comment: I have tried both using 'data:audio/x-wav;base64,' and following [this](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-protocol) tutorial(Windows Powershell). And both gave the same result.
Don't you feel any difference when listening through headphones?